# How To Save Data In Android's Internal Storage On A Click Of A Button using C#(Xamarin)

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, save

I want to save some kind of data on a click of a button to the internal memory of the android.
Actually i want to create the backup of the data.
Is there any such way?
Please help me with restoring of the backup as well.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If your data is Simple string then you need to create one Dependency Service in Xamarin Forms project and implement it into Android Project.
In Android Project use shared preference for save and retrieve data.

For Dependency service - https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/dependency-service/introduction/